# ESP32 crash even with empty main

Tags: crash, esp32

I made a second PCB of an already working device, but when I tried to upload the code to the esp, it crashes for some bizzar reason.
I'm using an PlatformIO Project based on arduino framework, the link to my repsitory: https://github.com/IsiTapier/PSMLightControl/tree/master/
My code broke with the new espressif32 platform 4.0 so I had to use version 3.5

I tried the same code on another esp, works fine.
I tried uploading empty code, works fine.
But when I upload the code with my classes just present, but with an empty main, it still crashes.

I have one class directly in the src dictionary and other classes (eg. display drivers and dmx libary) in the lib dictionary.
When I delete the class in src it works, aswell when I delete a lot of the includes of the others within that class.
I already tried to localize the issue but without any success, but since it works fine on another esp, i don't think its a software issue.
I also checked the powersupply and tried to add an external one, with usb connected it draws 0.3A and without only 0.1A.

I would be really pleased if someone could soon help me, I'm pretty desperate.

My hardware:
[PCB upside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcbOx.jpg)
[PCB downside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpMv6.jpg)

Here is the crash report:

```
rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x1b (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
load:0x40078000,len:10124
load:0x40080400,len:5828
entry 0x400806a8
Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core 0 register dump:
PC      : 0x400d9d44  PS      : 0x00060330  A0      : 0x800db927  A1      : 0x3ffe3b70  
A2      : 0x00000008  A3      : 0x00000140  A4      : 0x000001e0  A5      : 0x00000000
A6      : 0x00000001  A7      : 0x3ffc0970  A8      : 0x800d9d3d  A9      : 0x3ffe3b50  
A10     : 0x00000010  A11     : 0x00000001  A12     : 0x00000003  A13     : 0x3ffc0970
A14     : 0x00000007  A15     : 0x00000000  SAR     : 0x0000000f  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000018  LBEG    : 0x4000c2e0  LEND    : 0x4000c2f6  LCOUNT  : 0xffffffff

ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000

Backtrace: 0x400d9d44:0x3ffe3b70 0x400db924:0x3ffe3b90 0x400ef97b:0x3ffe3bb0 0x40082021:0x3ffe3bd0 0x40082250:0x3ffe3c20 0x40079247:0x3ffe3c40 0x400792ad:0x3ffe3c70 0x400792b8:0x3ffe3ca0 0x40079465:0x3ffe3cc0 0x400806da:0x3ffe3df0 0x40007c31:0x3ffe3eb0 0x4000073d:0x3ffe3f20

Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x1b (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
flash read err, 1000
ets_main.c 371
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
```

and here the one with an empty main:

```
 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x1b (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
load:0x40078000,len:10124
load:0x40080400,len:5828
entry 0x400806a8
Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core 0 register dump:
PC      : 0x40080fd1  PS      : 0x00060330  A0      : 0x800dc652  A1      : 0x3ffe3b40
A2      : 0x00000011  A3      : 0x00000002  A4      : 0x00000014  A5      : 0x3ffc09a4  
A6      : 0x00ff0000  A7      : 0x00000001  A8      : 0x3f404af4  A9      : 0xffffffff
A10     : 0xffffffff  A11     : 0x00000050  A12     : 0x08000000  A13     : 0x00000000  
A14     : 0xffffffff  A15     : 0x00000000  SAR     : 0x0000001e  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c
EXCVADDR: 0xffffffff  LBEG    : 0x4000c46c  LEND    : 0x4000c477  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  

ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000

Backtrace: 0x40080fd1:0x3ffe3b40 0x400dc64f:0x3ffe3b60 0x400dc738:0x3ffe3b90 0x400ef583:0x3ffe3bb0 0x40081ea1:0x3ffe3bd0 0x400820d0:0x3ffe3c20 0x40079247:0x3ffe3c40 0x400792ad:0x3ffe3c70 0x400792b8:0x3ffe3ca0 0x40079465:0x3ffe3cc0 0x400806da:0x3ffe3df0 0x40007c31:0x3ffe3eb0 0x4000073d:0x3ffe3f20

Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x1b (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
flash read err, 1000
ets_main.c 371
```

Comment: Did you try searching the web for info on this error, RTCWDT_RTC_RESET?

Comment: I finally found the problem, it was an short between the GPIO pins SD1, 15 and 2 which produced this wierd kind of software bug. Sometimes software and hardware are strangely interviened.

Answer (score 1):

finally found the problem, it was an short between the GPIO pins SD1, 15 and 2 which produced this wierd kind of software bug. Sometimes software and hardware are strangely interviened.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. It turns out the "Gnd" pin next to the 5v input pin is not actually ground. Firstly, a continuity test shows no link between that "GND" and the other actual GND pins. I had placed a capacitor between the 5v pin and the fake Gnd, removing the capacitor solved the issue. I hope this saves someone time.